# Convert pairs of elements to a matrix in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe of first event , second event and the occaurence. It consists of pairs in the following format:

```
(e1,e2,10)
(e1,e1,1)
(e1,e3,12)
(e2,e1,10)
(e2,e2,50)
```

Then, I want to write a csv file with the following format:

```
    e1 e2 e3
e1  1  10 12
e2  10 50 0
e3 12  0  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a dataset with three columns you can use groupBy, pivot and sum :

```
df.show
+---+---+-----+
| c1| c2|   c3|
+---+---+-----+
| e1| e2| 10.0|
| e1| e1|  1.0|
| e1| e4| 12.0|
| e1| e4|100.0|
| e2| e1| 10.0|
| e2| e2| 50.0|
+---+---+-----+

df.groupBy("c1").pivot("c2").sum("c3").show
+---+----+----+-----+                                                           
| c1|  e1|  e2|   e4|
+---+----+----+-----+
| e2|10.0|50.0| null|
| e1| 1.0|10.0|112.0|
+---+----+----+-----+
```

Note that I use "sum" so if you have the same pair of events more than once your occurrences will be summed. You can use any other aggregation function (avg, min, max...) if you want another behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe looks like this:

```
e1 | e2 | 10
e1 | e1 | 1
e1 | e4 | 12
e1 | e4 | 100
e2 | e1 | 10
e2 | e2 | 50
```

Give is column names to look like this (c1/c2/c3 are column names you can make these whatever you want)...

```
c1 | c2 | c3
---|----|----
e1 | e2 | 10
e1 | e1 | 1
e1 | e4 | 12
e1 | e4 | 100
e2 | e1 | 10
e2 | e2 | 50
```

And use a pandas data frame `pivot_table` function

Along the lines of (df is table name)..

```
df = df.pivot_table(values = 'c3', index = 'c1', columns = 'c2')
```

Which in theory would make it look like your expected output:

```
    e1  e2  e3
e1  1   10  12
e2  10  50  0
e3  12   0  0
```

Haven't tested